# Is there a way to check 3G speed connection on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, mobile, usb, 3g

I would like to know if there is a way to check the link speed of a 3G/mobile broadband USB Dongle I have connected on a Linux machine.

I am not talking about a speed test, but just the theoretical speed the link could achieve. Like the 100Mb on a typical ethernet connection.

Maybe with AT commands, but I did not find anything yet.

Thanks.

Comment: No general way to do this imho, you will need to reffer to manual of your product or some drivers. Kernel does not keep track of "theorethical" speeds and specifications unless specific driver support it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check speed with iperf http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/.